# combine 2 dim array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

I have a $array and I want to combine each second level elements as follow:

```
$array['A'] = array('a','b','c');
$array['B'] = array('d','e','f');
$array['C'] = array('g','h','i');

function combine($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array['A'] as $a)
        {
        foreach($array['B'] as $b)
        {
            foreach($array['C'] as $c)
            {
                $result[] = array($a,$b,$c);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The combine() works fine to show the correct result only if count($array) is 3. If I add more $array elements, for example, $array['D'] = array('j','k','l'), then it can't work correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

I think I should use recursive function. But I had not any experience with this type of programming.

Can you help me? It's making me crazy.

Comment: This question is clear because it doesn't express the exact desired result from the input (or modified input); therefore there is no [mcve].  Receiving answers that offer completely different solutions/results indicates an Unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, nice problem.  I've actually had to re-implement this on a number of occasions.  This ought to work for you:

```
    class Counter {
    private $bases;
    private $currNum;
    private $increment;
    private $maxVal;

    public function __construct($bases) {
        $this->bases = $bases;
        $this->maxVal = 1;
        $this->currNum = array();
        foreach ($bases as $base) {
            $this->maxVal *= $base;
            $this->currNum[] = 0;
        }
        $this->increment = 0;
    }

    public function increment() {
        ++$this->increment;
        for ($i = count($this->currNum) - 1; $i > -1; --$i) {
            $val = $this->currNum[$i] + 1;
            if ($val >= $this->bases[$i]) {
                $this->currNum[$i] = 0;
            } else {
                $this->currNum[$i] = $val;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO handle overflows
    public function hasNext() {
        return $this->increment < $this->maxVal;
    }

    public function getNum() {
        return $this->currNum;
    }

    public function getIncrement() {
        return $this->increment;
    }
}

// your sample arrays
$arrays = array(
array('a', 'b', 'c'),
array('d', 'e', 'f'),
array('g', 'h', 'i')
);

// parameter to counter changes based on how many arrays you have
// if you have 4 arrays of len 4, it'll be $counter = new Counter(array(4,4,4,4));
// it'll work with arrays of varying lengths as well.
// so if you have 1 array of len 2, another of len 3 and a third of len 4:
// $counter = new Counter(array(2,3,4));
$counter = new Counter(array(3,3,3));

$result = array();
while ($counter->hasNext()) {
    $indexes = $counter->getNum();
    //print_r($indexes);
    $result[] = array();
    foreach ($indexes as $arr => $index) {
        $result[count($result) - 1][] = $arrays[$arr][$index];
    }
    $counter->increment();
}

print_r($result);
```

I changed
$array['A']
$array['B']
to be indexed as
$array[0]
$array[1] etc to make it easier to work with.

```
counter->getNum()
```

returns the array indexes.  You can choose whether or not you want to actually pick that element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function *requires* its argument to be an array structured as such:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array()
    [B] => Array()
    [C] => Array()
)
```

I would imagine that adding another key 'D' doesn't actually break the function, you're just not getting the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array_map(null, $array['A'], $array['B'], $array['C'], $array['D'])` to do it.

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can construct an array of arrays, by using null as the callback.

Comment: Thank you xdazz, but array_map() cant solve the problem, because $array is a 7dim array and have more than 1000 elements. using array_map takes lots of GB of memory. I want to populate $result by choosing needed elements.

Comment: @Shila 7 dim array? That is not good for performance, maybe you should redesign your data structure.

Comment: It is not possible to change data structure, and I need not any performance improvements. server is enough powerful to handle requests and it's wasting time and money to change data structure.